# Game not detecting keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, gaming

Installed Control ultimate edition game (Game pass version), at the beginning it says press Enter to continue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/krrQx.jpg

but it doesn't work when i press it.
using latest Windows 10 20H2 update.
this is the only game having this problem. i play lots of games with game pass and none of them have any problem.

i have tried:

1. pressing every single key on the keyboard
2. leaving the game for 15 mins and try again
3. using on-screen keyboard
4. resetting and repairing the game from settings
5. restarting PC
6. installing VS runtimes 2015-2019
7. alt + tab or pressing win button to switch between programs

i have no idea what else to do.
when i first ran it, i successfully granted it access to my MSA.

my AV is Windows Defender, not blocking anything.

i don't use discord or any 3rd party overlay, even Steam is not installed.
only Xbox game bar is here which is required.

any help is appreciated

Comment: What exactly is “MSA”?

Comment: Microsoft Account

Comment: The problem is likely with the software not your machine.  [Here](https://fs30.formsite.com/505games/control/index.html) is how you can report the issue.  If you Twitter you can tweet to 505games and perhaps they can help.  I would try to also run the game as an Administrator (yes, apparently this might help).  Looks like that development branch of the game has [issues](https://mobile.twitter.com/505Support/status/1362104662665531392)

Comment: Thank you, I submitted a support ticket and waiting for a response from them.